# too big submits don't get through?

Tags: php, sql, submit

I have 74 pieces of text I'm sending to my database when I press <kbd>submit</kbd> on my page.

But when I press <kbd>submit</kbd> they aren't inserting into my Database?
When i do `data 1 = a, data 2 = b .... data 74 = bz` it's getting through.
Why does too big stream of data not insert?

i'd like to place the code but its much to big to put in here.

Comment: Start simple, cut it down to one piece of data and get that working. Then you can add more, in chunks, until you find the breaking point. It may not be what you're expecting.

Comment: what would you suggest? when i fill in a maximum of 2 characters. it gets through, but when i fill in more it fails.. seems to me my form is working ?:p

Comment: As I see it you have two potential problem areas for data loss.
The POST and the SQL statement. I would check these separately.
Try posting the data as normal, but instead of passing it to SQL right away, display the data and make sure all the variables are set with the correct values (You should only have to check the last variable/value).

Then take a look at the query you're generating, if you're trying to set 70+ fields at once, your query may be too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of post_max_size in your php.ini file in case it is set too low.

See the manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) for details

Comment: aa this is within the domain :( can't check it